# Align Dropdown with input in a responsive navbar

Tags: javascript, css

So im trying to create a responsive navbar with content in the left, middle and right. Right now, my search bar in the middle of the navbar, the drop down isnt aligned with it.

right now, the drop down content is just on the far left of the page.

I've tried left:0px already which dosnt work according to some other forums in stackoverflow

HTML

```
            <a href="./" class="active navleft">Cutlery</a>
            <a href="shops">Shops</a>
            <a href="mallpage.html">Malls</a>
            <div class = "searchdropdown">
                <input id ="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search..." onclick="searchDropToggle()" onkeyup="filterSearch()">
                <div id="searchDropdown" class="searchdropdown-content">
                    <a>testing</a>
                    <a>testing 2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--<button><img src = "images/icons/search.png"></button>-->
            <a v-if="!loggedIn" href="login" class="navright">Log in</a>
            <a v-if="loggedIn" class="navright" v-on:click.prevent="logout" href="">Sign Out</a>
            <a v-if="loggedIn" id = "profilebutton" :href = "`profile?id=${this.userid}`" class="navright">Profile</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="responsivenavbar()">
                <img style = "height:16px; width: 16px;" src = "images/icons/menu.png">
            </a>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #01333f;
  text-align: center;
}
  .navbar .navleft{
    float:left;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 9.5px 16px;
  }

  .navbar .navright{
    float: right;
  }

  .navbar button{
    background-color: teal ;
    height:30px;
    width: 30px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left:0;
    border:none;
    text-align: center;

  }

  .navbar button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .navbar button img{
    height:24px;
    width: 24px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }

  .navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  .navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #008ca0;
    color: white;
  }

  .navbar a.active {
    background-color: #008ca0;
    color: white;
  }

  .navbar .icon {
    display: none;
  }

  .searchdropdown{
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline;
    /*float:left;*/
    /*this float:left; dosnt work as it makes my input to the left of the nav bar which i do not want*/
  }


  .navbar input{
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    padding:3px 20px;
    border-radius:8px;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:7px;
  }

  .searchdropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .searchdropdown-content a {
    float:none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

.searchshow {display: block;}

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar a:not(:first-child), searchdropdown, .navbar input {
      display: none;
    }
    .navbar a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar.responsive {
      position: relative;
    }
    .navbar.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .navbar.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .navbar.responsive .searchdropdown {float: none; width: 100%; display: block;}
    .navbar.responsive .searchdropdown-content {position: relative;}
    .navbar.responsive input{display:block; width:100%; margin:0px; padding: 10px 20px;}
}
```

Lastly Javascript

```
function responsivenavbar() {

    var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
    }
}

function searchDropToggle(){
                document.getElementById("searchDropdown").classList.toggle("searchshow");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on css positioning [Css Positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the
>   nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the
>   viewport, like fixed).
>
> However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned
>   ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page
>   scrolling.

So you need to add a position to your parent class of your absolute positioned element `.searchdropdown-content`.  In this case that would be `.searchdropdown`.  Then you can absolutely position your `.searchdropdown-content` in the `.searchdropdown` div using top, left, right, and bottom.  Try adding the position of relative to `.searchdropdown` like so:

```
.searchdropdown{
  overflow:hidden;
  display: inline;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: doing this will fk up the dropdown during mobile responsive mode... and also make my dropdown inside the nav bar instead of outside

Comment: You need to use media queries for mobile and desktop widths and you need to use top, bottom, left and right to position your dropdown relative to the parent div.  You can position it 100% from the top to move it out of the navbar.  Read up on how to use absolute position.